# What does line 6 actually does do to check if a permuation is already displayed?

Tags: python-3.x, backtracking

''' I know that second condition in if statement is checking for already made permutation in case of input has repeated elements. But hows exactly is it done ! '''

```
def permutation(input_list, partial, used):
    if len(partial) == len(input_list):
        print(partial)
    else:
        for i in range(0, len(input_list)):
                if not used[i] and not (input_list[i] == input_list[i - 1] and not used[i - 1]):
                used[i] = True
                partial.append(input_list[i])
                permutation(input_list, partial, used)
                used[i] = False
                partial.pop(len(partial) - 1)


nums = [2,1,2,5]
used = [False for _ in range(0, len(nums))]
permutation(nums, [], used)
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement, `not used[i]` returns `False` for all cases except when `used[i]` is 0.
`input_list[i] == input_list[i - 1] and not used[i - 1]` checks if `input_list[i] == input_list[i - 1]` when `used[i -1]` is 0. And the final `not` negates it.